# How to test multiple bash function boolean return values at once in a single conditional?

Tags: bash, boolean, return-value

The title "should" suffice.

I'll post a solution myself for the benefit of others, since I couldn't find a simple, generic one at the time.

Comment: "More specific" because it's about C++, not Bash.

Comment: @StefanvandenAkker - thanks for spotting that! I'll remove the link. Posted in haste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if func1 "$arg1" && func2 "$arg2"; then
    echo 'both succeeded'
fi

if func1 "$arg1" || func2 "$arg2"; then
    echo 'at least one succeeded'
fi

if ! func1 "$arg1" && ! func2 "$arg2"; then
    echo 'both failed'
fi

if ! func1 "$arg1" || ! func2 "$arg2"; then
    echo 'at least one failed'
fi
```

The key points being:

- Bash considers function return value `0` to mean `true` and `1` or another integer to mean `false`
- One must use the boolean logical operators `&&` and `||`
- Also take care to leave a space between `!` and a function when testing for failure

Comment: so you found the answer to your question, arguments should be quoted to avoid splitting, and the second function may not be called (after `&&` when the first condition is false or `||` when the first condition is true).

Comment: Good point, thanks @NahuelFouilleul - quotes added.